# BASH: Looking for a way to import functions into the global scope from within a function

Tags: bash, scope

I'm writing a number of scripts that all depend on any number of "library" scripts.
My scripts are built together mainly with functions and in one of these functions named "init", I define the constants I need and try to import my libraries using "source". However, if I try to call one of the functions in the global scope or inside of another function it doens't seem to exist...

For declaring global variables there's "declare -g", is there an option like that for functions?
for reference, the scripts I'm writing reside here: [Pegasus' Linux Administration Tools](https://github.com/pegasusict/PLAT/)

Comment: If a file containing a function is sourced then it should be global.  Can you show some code which fails?  (in your question, not as a link)

Comment: for instance:
`create_constants() {
 # declare extensions
 declare -gr INI_EXT=".ini"
 declare -gr LIB_EXT=".inc.bash"
 declare -gr LOG_EXT=".log"
 declare -gr LIB_DIR="lib/"
 declare -gr SYS_LIB_DIR="/var/lib/plat/"
 declare -gr SYS_BIN_DIR="/usr/bin/plat/"
 declare -gr LOG_DIR="/var/log/plat/"
 declare -gr INI_FILE="$SCRIPT$INI_EXT"
 declare -gr INI_PRSR="$LIB_DIRini_parser$LIB_EXT"
 declare -gr LIB_FILE="functions$LIB_EXT"
 declare -gr LIB="$LIB_DIR$LIB_FILE"
}

import_libs() {
 source "$LIB"
 source "$INI_PRSR"
}

### MAIN ###
create_constants
import_libs
`

Comment: I had to leave stuff out because of the max length and my layout had been messed up...

Comment: https://github.com/pegasusict/BASH_FUNC_LIB/blob/master/default.inc.bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can export function the same way as variables :

```
myfun() {
  ...
}

export -f myfun
```

Comment: so, for each function I define in those libs that needs to be global I should export it?

Comment: Yes, actually it creates a global variable (as normal variables) with the function body inside it and so it is callable

Comment: Also take a look here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430690 if you want to import all defined functions and variables

Comment: the idea for my suite is to be portable, so hooking it into an rc file is not ideal, but thanks you've given me food for thought